# Retrieve the data from the relationship in parse DB through Rest API

Tags: rest, parse-platform, parse-rest-api

I am been going through the parse DB but got stuck at one issue. The issue is How can I retrieve the data from the relationship in parse DB.

For ex: I have two table

- Department
- Employee

Department table structure is:

- ObjectId
- departmentId
- deparmentName

Employee table structure is:

- ObjectId
- EmployeeName
- Age
- department

In the Employee table i have created one column with department and added the relation With Department table.
I have successfully added the records and created a relation. And when i am clicking on View Relation in department column i am getting the data for the associated Department.

I have given the curl command to get the data:

```
Curl -X GET <my application Id> <my rest api key>
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Employee
```

I am getting the result as

> {"results":[{"department":{"__type":"Relation","className":"Department"},"createdAt":"2015-08-07T08:53:23.220Z","objectId":"AkceV0fwW","updatedAt":"2015-08-07T09:04:45.362Z","userName":"XYZ"}]}

Now how to retrieve the objectId of the Department in this result means I want to get the department name for this Employee.

Comment: Check the docs: https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide/#queries-relational-queries

Comment: @wain .. according to the doc i should know the objectId of the department class. But my requirement is I want to retreive the ObjectId of deparment class from the Employee Class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Department class doesn't have an `objectId`, instances of that class do, and your statement means you're thinking about the relationship query backwards.

The relation holds multiple instances (potentially). If you just want one then you should use a pointer as it's much easier.

With a relation you use the `objectId` of the container and the name of the relation to do a query on the contained class:

```
GET https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Department

'where={"$relatedTo":{"object":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Employee","objectId":"AkceV0fwW"},"key":"department"}}'
```

Comment: Thanx @Wain.. for suggesting the pointer and got your query also